# Why my js's subfolder is (on sublime) with a faint gray?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my project of ruby on rails on the texts editor "sublime" presents some folders with some kind of unselected and faint gray. And this happens to my subcarpet "packs" in "public"'s folder, so, when I push to github, all the js's info that is in those folders didn't push, so when I tried to clone it and turn on rails s, the webpage sent me an error, becaus it didn't find this folder.

Do anyone knows how to fix it?
Hope I did explain myself.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's because they're being ignored by git.  Check the file `.gitignore` in the root of your project.

But there's a reason they're being ignored... check your webpacker.yml to see if you have `compile: true` and `check_yarn_integrity: true` and many of those folders will be created for you when you run rails s in development mode. In production mode, you should compile them manually.

Comment: You are right, thank you, but I am new in RoR, I am not sure where I could modify or find these lines of the webpacher and how could I avoid that this in future projects or pushes to git?

Comment: `webpacker.yml ` is in your `config` folder. When you cloned it, was that to another development machine?  Or your production machine?  And are you running in the production environment?

Comment: I am usingthe same machine, so I make some files and sent them to github, everything worked fine, but when I tried to make my first clone, everything was ok, but when I go to rails s, the webpage send me the error of the absence of this subflders in the "public" 's  folder. I tried to make new files and this repeats. What I see is that (when I am creating my new files, the webpacker have some issues, but it seems that the problem is fixed alone and the file is created. https://github.com/eduardosilvin/fintual1